# Annihilator of image $T$ equals to $\text{ker}(T^*)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear transformation, then $\text{Ann}(\text{Im}T)=\text{ker}T^*$.

How one could start to prove it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\phi\in Ann(ImT)$ iff $\phi(Tx)=0$ for all $x\in v$ iff $T^*(\phi) x=0$ for all $x\in V$ iff $\phi\in Ker(T^*)$